# If an INDEX exist in Listbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I am running a Do Until Loop and its giving the error Index out of range. I am using this code:

```
If Not imgList.Item(i).ToString = Nothing Then
```

but its not working..
Actually this loop (in a private sub) is called before addition of any value in the Listbox..

here is the complete loop..

```
Dim i As Integer = 0

Do Until i = pagesRange
       If Not imgList.Item(i).ToString = Nothing Then
          'other code
          i += 1

       Else

       End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

for the given code to avoid Index out of range exception try below

```
If imgList.Count < i AndAlso Not (imgList.Item(i).ToString Is Nothing) Then

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember about Zero Based ..

```
Dim i As Integer = 0

Do Until i = pagesRange -1
       If Not imgList.Item(i).ToString = Nothing Then
          'other code
          i += 1

       Else

       End If
       'why i += 1 not here ?
Loop
```